# Simple Stateless with Descriptor: ClassNotFoundException: LocalInitialContextFactory

Tags: java, ejb

I'm beginning to lean EJB, and I'm trying to run the sample: http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-stateless-with-descriptor/README.html

...and I got:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: simpleStatelessWithDescriptor.LocalInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simpleStatelessWithDescriptor.LocalInitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
    at simpleStatelessWithDescriptor.CalculatorTest.setUp(CalculatorTest.java:17)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: simpleStatelessWithDescriptor.LocalInitialContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:46)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:654)
    ... 18 more
```

My file tree is:

[image]

I searched and replaced in all file the package names to meet the file tree.

Now, what's still missing? Why it can't find the LocalInitialContextFactory?

I'm on Windows 10 64bits, Eclipse Neon, java 6 (can't update for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simpleStatelessWithDescriptor.LocalInitialContextFactory`  doesn't exist in your classes and you should not declare it.

You should use `org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory` if you follow the example. You have not the class in your classpath because I imagine you have not added it. Adding each needed library may be long and complex.
You should use the pom.xml as proposed in the example.

Some advices if I can  : 
Install Maven, learn the basis to use it, checkout the project from scratch and build it with Maven:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/trunk/examples/simple-stateless-with-descriptor/